# Google Apps Script - ReplaceText vertical tab

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, replace, special-characters, re2

Whenever I paste text into a Google Docs document, all the newline characters get convereted into vertical tab characters (\013 OR \v). This happens regardless of the source of the clipboard text (webpage, word, notepad++).

Usually this means I have to work my way through the document clearing all the vertical tabs and replacing them with proper newlines by backspacing the character and hitting return. However, I want to write a script to replace all the characters in the doc at once. The Replace ui feature doesn't support newline characters but I'm hoping the scripting api does.

I have written the code below, but though it runs, the vertical tab characters are not replaced. I can still see hundreds in the document with the find/replace ui feature. What am I doing wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("\\v", "\n");
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue where on copy paste newline is converted to vertical tabs. Try using Logger if you are really finding them in the first place. `body.findText(pattern)`

Comment: `body.replaceText("\\v+", "\n");
}` ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested Sunil, and I'm definately finding vertical tabs. I can confirm that there are no vertical tabs in the text before copying out of notepad++, yet they exist in the GDoc after paste. Reproducing this on multiple computers at home and at work.

Comment: Very inconvenient.

Comment: Would you try this?

https://gist.github.com/hotohoto/ba01d4b53edeef1005181ee95f6dfb13

Comment: This approach does work hotohoto. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer by hotohoto in the comments above, I paste it here in case the gist gets removed:

```
function removeVerticalTabs() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var bodyText = body.getText();
  bodyText = bodyText.replace( /\r/g, "\n" );
  body.setText( bodyText );
}
```